# Animation style ease, ease-out etc. is not working in my javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, animation

I have a function that animates the addition of margin to a div-box, but for some reason easeOut animation style is not working for me. Linear animation style works fine tho.

Here is the function:

```
$("#bokse1").click(function() {
  $("#nav").animate({
    marginLeft: ["+=100px", "linear"],
  }, 400, function() {});
});
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hto5qLmb/1/

I wanted to make it like this:

```
 marginLeft: ["+=100px", "easeOut"],
```

but it is not working.

Comment: It works like this: http://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1q0boa73/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like jQuery really does not want to play nice with easing out with that type of animation selector, if you still want to have the ease out effect, use:

```
$("#bokse1").click(function() {
  $("#nav").animate({ "margin-left": "+=50px" }, "easeOut" );
});
```

Additionally, have a look at your developer tools, and you can see the myriad of erros that fire when you attempt to use the easing in the way you did initially. Strange indeed

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I now have a more compact and easier to read code, too! Althought, now I am not sure how to change the speed of the animation. Could you help one more time?

Comment: There's a duration parameter which for default uses 400ms. You have to set it after the first param, here's the doc: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: I dont understand. I am trying to do this: ... }, 2000, "easeOut" ); ... but its not working

Comment: `.animate({ "margin-left": "+=50px" }, 1000 );`  will set it to be 1000 ms

Comment: But then how do I set the animation style ease-out? I want ease-out to last for lets say 1000 ms, how do I do that? Thought "... }, 2000, "easeOut" ); ..." would fix the problem, but the whole thing crashes instead.

Comment: Weird, according to the docs that should work, however I ran that just then and it fires a lot of errors.... looks like a bug in the jQuery. Perhaps try with different css modifiers :/

Comment: Whats also weird is that the original code was working fine for linear and default animation style, but did not work for the other animation styles.

Comment: jQuery has to sort itself out haha, to be honest I find myself custom building the CSS for the animations, then just call toggle on those classes to do the animation. Less lifting on javascript, and more on the reliable CSS

Comment: Yeah, right. It is not a big deal for me right now, but the problem could bother some people so hopefully they fix it soon. And btw, thank you for your help! :)

Comment: No worries, if you need more help, feel free to contact me, i check instagram more often @anthonycarnell